# The best constant of Liouville’s approximation theorem

Tags: number-theory, approximation

Liouville’s approximation theorem says:

> If $\alpha$ is algebraic irrational of degree $n\geq2$,
> then there exists a real number $A$ such that for all integers
> $p,q$ with $q>0$ and
> $$\left|\alpha-\frac{p}{q}\right|>\frac{A}{q^n}.$$

I am interested in the constant $A$, is there a best $A=A(n,\alpha)$ in the follows sense
$$A(n,\alpha)=:\inf_{p\geq0,q\geq1}q^n\cdot\left|\alpha-\frac{p}{q}\right|
=\inf_{p\geq0,q\geq1}q^{n-1}\cdot|q\alpha-p|.$$
There are some partial result in the special cases: for $n=2$,
$$\left|\sqrt{2}-\frac{p}{q}\right|>\frac{1}{3q^2},\quad
\left|\sqrt{3}-\frac{p}{q}\right|>\frac{1}{5q^2}，$$
and (with $\alpha=\sqrt d$) [$$\left|\sqrt{d}-\dfrac{p}{q}\right|\geq\frac{1}{q^2(2\sqrt{d}+1)},\quad 
\left|\sqrt{d}-\dfrac{p}{q}\right|\geq\dfrac{\sqrt{d+1}-\sqrt{d}}{q^2}.$$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1530454/bound-on-difference-between-irrational-square-root-and-rational-number/1530988#1530988)

In the case $\alpha=\sqrt2,n=2$, it seems
$$\inf_{p\geq0,q\geq1}q\left|\sqrt{2}q-p\right|
=\frac{2}{3+2\sqrt{2}}\ \text{when}\ p=3,q=2.$$

In the case $\alpha=\sqrt3,n=2$, it seems
$$\inf_{p\geq0,q\geq1}q\left|\sqrt{3}q-p\right|
=\frac{1}{\sqrt3+2}\ \text{when}\ p=2,q=1.$$

> If there are some colsed form for the best constant $A(n,\alpha)$ or in some special cases such as $n=2$.
> Any help and hints will welcome, thanks!

Comment: As far as I know, $n$ can be any real number greater than $2$, but not $2$ itself. Roth's theorem might be what you are looking for.

Comment: @ Peter  I know Roth's theorem, thank you.

Comment: If I interpreted this correctly, isn't your infimum 0 if the degree of $\alpha$ is greater than 2 by Roth's theorem as Peter mentioned, and given by the Markov spectrum if the degree is 2?

Comment: @ Derivative, what I mean is for fixed degree $n$. It should be $A(n,\alpha)>A(n+1,\alpha)$ and $A(n,\alpha)\to0$ as $n\to\infty$.

Comment: Oh I see you have just the infimum, not the limit inferior. This makes the question much harder. In this case you can produce pathological examples like $\alpha=1+\sqrt{2}\cdot 10^{-100}+\sqrt{2}\cdot 10^{-10000}$, so you have some very good small approximations, even though they don't reflex the approximations of $\alpha$ in general. Btw if you put a space after the @ the other person doesn't get pinged.